# bootstrap-select add item and select it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using Silvio Moreto's Bootstrap Select.

On my page I have a button that opens a modal with an input box that allows you to add an item to the selectpicker.  I would then like to automatically have that item selected but I can't get it to work.

The code I have is :

```
$('#myselect').append('<option val="'+newitemnum+'">'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
$('#myselect').val(newitemnum);
$('#myselect').selectpicker('refresh');
```

But it just doesn't  work.  The item doesn't get selected.

I have tried replacing the selection line with :

```
$('#myselect').selectpicker('val',newitemnum);
```

but that doesn't work either

Any ideas much appreciated (although the item DOES get added to the selectpicker).

Comment: According to the [library docs](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), your 2nd code snippet should yield the expected results. Does it show any error messages in the console after running that statement?

Comment: nothing at all,  it adds the value to the selectpicker but just doesn't select it - it defaults it to "Nothing Selected"

Comment: If all the solutions above aren't working, double check that your selector is valid, e.g: console.log($('#myselect')); If not, you may have a problem with your select id.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You have a typo.  Instead of:

```
$('#myselect').append('<option val="'+newitemnum+'">'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
```

You need:

```
$('#myselect').append('<option value="'+newitemnum+'">'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
```

Here is a JSFiddle demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/xbr5agqt/

The "Add and select 'Soy Sauce' option" button does the following:

```
$("#myselect").append('<option value="'+newitemnum+'">'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
$("#myselect").val(4);
$("#myselect").selectpicker("refresh");
```

One slightly faster approach (used by the "Add and select 'Relish' option" button) is to append the new <option> element with the `selected` attribute already applied:

```
$("#myselect").append('<option value="'+newitemnum+'" selected="">'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
$("#myselect").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Comment: Awesome!  That was it!  Facepalm!  Serisouly,  amazing how someone else looking at your code can spot somethig obvious (val instead of value) that you have been searching for, for hours.  Thanks v much :)

Comment: is it woking in searchable selctpiker ?

Comment: i cant get it to work in searchable picker

Answer (score 5):

For adding `options` dynamically in `bootstrap-selectpicker`, `append` the `option` to the `select` and `refresh` the `selectpicker`

```js
$(document).on('click','#addOptions',function(){
  var newitemnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var newitemdesc = "Item "+ newitemnum;
  
  // Append the option to select
  $('#myselect').append('<option value="'+newitemnum+'">'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
  
  // Set the select value with new option
  $("#myselect").val(newitemnum);
  
  // Refresh the selectpicker
  $("#myselect").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select name="myselect[]" class="selectpicker" id="myselect">
  <option value="A1">Anatomy</option>
  <option value="A2">Anesthesia</option>
  <option value="A3">Biochemistry</option>
  <option value="A4">Community Medicine</option>
  <option value="A5">Dermatology</option>
  <option value="A6">ENT</option>
</select>

<button id="addOptions" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
```

For better, add the `selected` attribute in the append option

```
// Append the option to select
$('#myselect').append('<option value="'+newitemnum+'" selected>'+newitemdesc+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working on the searchable & multiselect selectpiker :

```
 <select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" multiple data-live-search="true" title="Persons"
            data-selected-text-format="static" data-actions-box="true">
 </select>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
                $("#mySelect").append(
                    `<option value="${i}">person ${i}</option>`
                );
            
            $("#mySelect").selectpicker("refresh");
            $('.bs-select-all').html("All");
            $('.bs-deselect-all').html("Nothing");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that using jQuery select2.Eg.

```
<select class="form-control" id="tagsExample">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>

$("#tagsExample").select2({
  tags: true
});
```

Reference: https://select2.org/tagging